# Server is swapping regardless of available memory

Tags: ram, swap

Here is some `vmstat` output

```
x@x-server:~$ vmstat 1
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0 223104 123116  67944 521656    0    1     3     4   16   32  1  0 99  0  0
 0  0 223104 123116  67944 521656    0    0     0     0   38   74  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0 223104 123116  67944 521656    0    0     0     0   31   64  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0 223104 122944  67944 521560    0    0     0     0  126  145  1  0 99  0  0
 0  0 223052 122820  67944 521560   64    0    72     0   83  145  0  1 98  0  0
 0  0 223000 122820  67944 521560   64    0    64     0   60  114  1  0 99  1  0
 0  0 223000 122820  67944 521560    0    0     0     0   44   78  0  1 100  0  0
 0  0 223000 122820  67944 521560    0    0     0     0   27   56  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0 223000 122820  67952 521552    0    0     0    24   82  145  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0 223000 122820  67952 521560    0    0     0     0   42   86  0  1 100  0  0
 0  0 222952 122696  67952 521560   32    0    32     0   75  127  1  0 100  0  0
 0  0 222952 122696  67952 521560    0    0     0     0   28   58  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0 222896 122448  67952 521560   48    0    48     0   90  127  1  0 99  0  0
 0  0 222896 122448  67952 521560    0    0     0     0   31   63  0  1 100  0  0
 0  0 222896 122448  67952 521560    0    0     0     0   31   62  0  0 100  0  0
```

And here is `free`

```
x@x-server:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1430         734         119          25         575         636
Swap:          1467         217        1250
```

As you can see I got some swap action going on even though I got a bunch of memory (around 50%) available. Why is that and how can I make it use that memory?

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine which process is using  the swap memory use this below command and check. If you don't wanted that process kill it and proceed

> for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk '/VmSwap|Name/{printf $2 " "
>   $3}END{ print ""}' $file; done | sort -k 2 -n -r | less

Comment: Well it seems like a bunch of processes are using swap (50+)